# regular expressions metacharacters screening

Tags: c#, regex, metacharacters

To find substring I use regEx `pattern = "^value\s\w+\s\d+$"`, where value sometimes contains metacharacters. I just need to know if it is possible to make metacharacters from value not to be interpret as metacharacters?

Comment: for example i need to find next string: Value (addInfo) record 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
"^" + RegEx.Escape(value) + @"\s\w+\s\d+$"
```

Comment: Incidentally, you may want to use \s+ instead of \s